# JQuery mobile: test offline

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile

I am new in JQuery Mobile. I really like it but I have 2 basic questions:

1- Can I test the app OFFLINE in my iPhone?

I know how to see the app when I am with an Internet connection even how to create the icon. But I don't see how to see the app i I don't have an Internet connection.

2- I suppose I can sent the html and css made with jQuery Mobile to Apple as any app. And it will work offline. Is that right?

Is there anyone with experience who have done apps with JQuery Mobile and are working in the app store?

Comment: How do you use jQuery Mobile? I think you could put it on a server and access it with your wifi connexion and a browser.

Comment: What I am asking is how to use JQuery Mobile OFFLINE, WITHOUT AN INTERNET CONNECTION.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, you can have a jQuery Mobile page completely offline.** [Download the necessary libraries](http://code.jquery.com/) to your device. For the example I used the following

- jquery-1.8.0.min.js
- jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js

Additionally you need the jQuery Mobile CSS structure file

- jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css

Then use the [theme roller](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/themes.html) to create your own CSS (or without changes just use the default jQuery CSS) and download it including the icon sets to your device. For the example I used this CSS name

- taifun.min.css

The icon sets are stored in the subdirectory `/images`.

**example code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Offline</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="taifun.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="content">
    <h1>I'm a jQuery Mobile offline page</h1>
    <ul data-role="listview">
      <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/content -->
</body>
</html>
```

**screenshot HTC Desire**
[image: screenshot]

Comment: this sounds like you somehow made some kind of error... unfortunately we never will know, what kind of error that might be... [you can see my working example also here](https://puravidaapps.com/listview.php)

Answer (score 1):

1. @Brice Favre is right - testing 'offline' could be achieved by hosting your app on a LAN and accessing it using your iPhone through Wifi.
2. If you 'host' the app using e.g. PhoneGap, and include all the libaries (jQuery, jQuery Mobile) and CSS as part of your application, then your app will function just fine without an Internet connection - many apps work this way. See this [PhoneGap tutorial](http://phonegap.com/start).

Comment: 1. I don't understand your answer, if I access through wifi this is  online, with an internet connection. What I am asking is how to access to an app made with jQuery mobile when I am without internet connection.

Comment: If you want to test on an actual device, then the device will need to connect to a server/host somewhere, such as your local network, in order get the actual files. There is no (legal) way to copy the files to a device and then loading the local files on the device. Alternatively, you could wrap the jQuery mobile project in a container project such as PhoneGap, and install it on your device (assuming that you have licenses for everything).

Comment: 2. PhoneGap seems to be another thing. Something to add to any html project. I wanted to know jQuery Mobile. Can jQuery Mobile alone be used to make apps and send them to Apple?

Comment: jQuery Mobile on its own is not sufficient to built an app which could be installed on a device, no.

Comment: I cannot install PhoneGap. I donwload it and I don't even see the icon to install that I see in the video: http://phonegap.com/start , I have a Mac OS 10.7.3. Any idea where could be the problem?

Comment: The PhoneGap download is a ZIP file, which you would need to extract first (probably in the Downloads folder), before getting to the installer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9414/discussion-between-narcis-and-ryan-bates)

Comment: Sorry - don't have time to chat now. Good luck!