# Use jQuery mobile offline

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, javascript-framework

I am developing on an Android mobile system, using PhoneGap with jQuery mobile. I need my app to work without internet connection. I read the two articles from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892136/jquery-mobile-test-offline) and [THERE](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/3/12/Building-an-offline-capable-mobile-web-site-with-jQuery-Mobile), trying to import all the required files about jQuery Mobile to my Phonegap app. But it still doesn't work properly without internet.

Here are the file structure and manifest cache, I do also include the JavaScript and CSS file:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Did I miss anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared a jQuery Mobile offline example. [Please find detailed info how to do it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892136/jquery-mobile-test-offline/13222844#13222844)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you serving up your manifest file with the correct `MIME` type? The manifest needs to be sent with the `text/cache-manifest` `MIME` type.

Also while I can't say for sure why you application isn't working, one thing to keep in mind is that in a `phonegap` application the initial page is served up from the filesystem so if you have all your pages bundled together in your `phonegap` application you shouldn't a manifest file to make it offline.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't know what is
"serving up your manifest file with the correct MIME type"
can you explain more?

Comment: If you need more information of what a MIME type is you should be able to find more information with a basic search (its basically an identifier for files). To send the file with the right MIME type you may need to configure your web server to send the manifest file with the right MIME/contentType, how to do so depends on what kind of server your using.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. But I use a mobile device, is that any relationship with the web server? And can't I just include the jQuery mobile files?Why not? What's the difference between this and the hyperlink method.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my reply you shouldn't need the manifest file at all in your phonegap application as long as you include all your files (including the JQM ones).

Answer (score 0):

you also need to specify network and fallback(optional) as follows :

Line starting with # are comment

```
# (*) online whitelist wildcard flag
NETWORK:
*

#This is optional
#FALLBACK:
#/ /offline.php
```