# where to include the jquery and jquery mobile libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using the following libraries:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

If I include the above in the `<HEAD>` tags the application works as expected. My question is, If I open the same web page in the browser, after downloading all three libraries and then include them in folders CSS and JS respectively and then use the following code:

```
<script rel="external" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>              
<script rel="external" type="text/javascript" src="js/jqm.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jqm.css"/>
```

The program doesn't work. I have tried including them in the last line of the body tag but it's still not working.

Comment: Are you sure your paths and filenames are correct? You can also bag the `rel="external"`.

Comment: What directory structure do you have?... the above won't work if your "pages" are nested deeper than your root.

Comment: @j08691 i tried without the rel = "external" still it is not working

Comment: It must be your file paths if you have these files on your server.

Comment: @scunliffe the structure is a folder of desktop by name www and inside it is index.html and js folder which has jq and jqm lib and css folder which has jqm css

Comment: @AlexRichards i'm running it locally

Comment: Ok. For example; the files are in http://localhost/js/jquery.js If the page you are accessing is at http://localhost/folder/file.html then the JS file is not going to be found because you are not in the same directory (your up one level).

Comment: @AlexRichards the structure is simple

www--->css
www--->js
www--->index.html

and inside css folder is the jqm css file and inside js folder is the jq and jqm js files

Comment: Ok - have you checked in your browsers error console or your webserver logs for any 404 messages?

Comment: You could try referencing them absolutely. (i.e. /www/js/{file} and /www/cs/{file}). Not the best of ideas though especially if your structure is subject to change in the future.

Comment: @AlexRichards i did an alert in the jqm js file in document.ready().... it is coming up... so that mean there is a problem is ajax loading.... i've a link to 2nd page but on click of that link a blank page is loaded.... but if i include the <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> then its working fine

Comment: thanks guys... got it.. there was problem only with the css file probably coz of compression... i'm now calling only css from net rest all js is coming from the www/js folder....

Comment: Do you have any debugger output for us to look at?  This is a vague question

Comment: _i'm now calling only css from net_ with my solution below you also can store the css file locally, but you will need the iconsets, too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store your libraries on your device and it also will work without internet access.
 I once prepared an example, [see here how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892136/jquery-mobile-test-offline/13222844#13222844)...

[image]

Your example does not work, because you did not download the iconsets. You have to store them in the subdirectory `/images`. Also you have to use the the jQuery Mobile CSS structure file...